# Memory Max Settings Not Working in SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 & Windows 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have set max memory settings for SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 instance but it's not working and consuming more than the defined amount of memory.

I am facing slow performance issue on db server.

Any idea how to fix this issue and can I find which process is consuming more memory space?

Comment: Max server memory only controls buffer pool / plan cache; SQL Server can use a lot of memory outside of that. If you want all of sqlservr.exe to use 13 GB of memory, you need to set max server memory to something lower than that. You have more control in SLQ Server 2012+, but it's still not *everything*: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlosteam/archive/2012/07/12/memory-manager-configuration-changes-in-sql-server-2012.aspx

Comment: If task manager is showing 5gb and you said max level is valid for only BPOOL then from where i can get exact idea which memory process is actually using exact memory? How can i speedup my db performance without restarting ?

Comment: Some ideas here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/84442/1186 Also, why do you think SQL Server is slow *because* it is using a lot of memory? This is exactly how SQL Server *speeds up* - by using more memory. Do you think using less memory and forcing more operations to go through slow disk will speed it up? If you have performance problems you are certainly chasing the wrong culprit.

Comment: Any luck for new ideas